# Magento 2 + Varnish + Nginx + Multiple Order Placed from IPs

Tags: magento2, nginx, varnish

I am having a similar problem. the "Placed from IP" for all of my sales emails looks like this : 127.0.0.1 (XX.XXX.XX.XX, yy.yyy.yy.yy, 127.0.0.1)

I believe the correct IP is the one marked as xx.xxx.xx.xx. I also suspects this has something to do with my varnish configuration with Nginx. But I'm not sure how to fix it. Below is my Varnish setup. Any help would be appreciated.

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6081;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    proxy_buffer_size 128k;
    proxy_buffers 4 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because there are multiple nodes in the chain, each of their IP addresses is added to the `X-Forwarded-For` header. As you have noticed, the first IP address represents the client IP.

### Resetting X-Forwarded-For

Here's how you set the `X-Forwarded-For` header with the client IP:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if(req.http.X-Real-IP) {
        set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = req.http.X-Real-IP;
    }
}
```

Because the Nginx configuration also sets an `X-Real-IP` header, we can use that value to set the `X-Forwarded-For` header.

### Using the PROXY protocol

A more conventional solution, is to really on the `PROXY` protocol. [This protocol was invented by the folks at *HAProxy*](https://www.haproxy.org/download/1.8/doc/proxy-protocol.txt) and adds connection information in the preamble of the TCP packet.

Varnish supports this, and many other technologies do as well.

You can configure Varnish to also listen for incoming `PROXY` connections:

```
varnishd -a :80 -a :8443,PROXY -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl
```

In addition to an HTTP listener on port `80`, I've added a PROXY listener on port `8443`.

There are various TLS proxies that support the PROXY protocol as well, and that can be connected to Varnish over `PROXY`.

Varnish's [Hitch](http://hitch-tls.org/) TLS proxy is one of them. [HaProxy](https://www.haproxy.org/) obviously supports it as well. Nginx does too, but only in its Enterprise version.

The benefit of using `PROXY` is that the original client IP address is transported end-to-end and doesn't get altered in the `X-Forwarded-For` header.

If Varnish accepts a `PROXY` connection, it will automatically set `X-Forwarded-For` to the original client IP and avoid any confusion.

> Although this is the better solution, if you use the open source version of Nginx and you'r not willing to use Hitch for TLS termination, just use the VCL example I mentioned above and you'll be fine.

Comment: I believe that my varnish is already setup to use a proxy listener. If I go to /etc/systemd/system and find the varnish service, it is set like this:ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd \
          -a :6081 \
          -a localhost:8443,PROXY \
          -p feature=+http2 \
          -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
          -s malloc,256m
But I still multiple IP addresses being returned. Maybe I am not fully understanding your answer however.

Answer (score 1):

When Magento is behind a proxy or caching server there will be multiple possible source IP addresses being passed to PHP in the backend. In your NGINX config you are setting the *X-REAL-IP* and *X-FORWARDED-FOR* headers. You can tell Magento to use these extra server values to determine client IP addresses.

The client IP is being returned from `Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment::getRemoteAddress()`

To add alernative headers for client IP address you can inject extra arguments into the **$alternativeHeaders** array of this class.

One way to do this is via an xml di config file in `app/etc/myconfig/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
     <type name="Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\RemoteAddress">
         <arguments>
            <argument name="alternativeHeaders" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="x-client-ip" xsi:type="string">HTTP_X_REAL_IP</item>
                <item name="x-forwarded-for" xsi:type="string">HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
     </type>
</config>
```

After adding this file run `bin/magento setup:di:compile`

It is worth noting that if your server has both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses then you also need to enable NGINX for IPv4 and IPv6.